# split() not splitting all white spaces?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, split

I am trying to take a text document and write each word separately into another text document. My only issue is with the code I have sometimes the words aren't all split based on the white space and I'm wondering if I'm just using .split wrong? If so, could you explain why or what to do better?

Here's my code:

```
    list_of_words = []

with open('ExampleText.txt', 'r') as ExampleText:
    for line in ExampleText:
        for word in line.split(''):
            list_of_words.append(word)
            print("Done!")
    print("Also done!")

with open('TextTXT.txt', 'w') as EmptyTXTdoc:
    for word in list_of_words:
        EmptyTXTdoc.write("%s\n" % word)

EmptyTXTdoc.close()
```

This is the first line in the ExampleText text document as it is written in the newly created EmptyTXTdoc:

Submit
a personal
statement
of
research
and/or
academic
and/or
career
plans.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using `line.split('')` or `line.split(' ')`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'd been messing around with the input and forgot! I'd intended to use line.split(), which is what produces the example I gave.

Comment: `for word in line.split():` should have worked (that is, without `''`).  Could you try it again, double-checking the code, and adding `print(repr(word))`  right before the `append`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split()` (or `.split(' ')` for only *spaces*) instead of `.split('')`.

---

Also, consider sanitizing the `line` with `.strip()` for every iteration of the file, since the line is accepted with a newline (`\n`) in its end.

Comment: Of course one can use regex, but do you have any explanation on why `"a personal".split(" ")` would not work as expected in the case in question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest By "whitespace" one usually means spaces **and** tabs (and usually also newlines). I'll just note that if not using regex, one should use `.strip` to sanitize newlines.

Answer (score 0):

`.split('')` Will not remove a space because there isn't a space in between the two apostrophes. You're telling it to split on, well, nothing.